# How can I align my mini-cart back to normal. (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, minicart

I had done some modifications for my WooCommerce and indirectly modified my mini-cart (shown in the image). What I had done here is I added my own custom function to place my thumbnail/image next to the name of the product (Shown on the third and fourth image) and I get what I wanted for my cart section and review order section. I also added SKU for all of the product reviews but it duplicates as well in my mini-cart. Just wanna ask is there any way I can change back to the original layout of my mini-cart back to normal without changing/removing my custom function.

The second image will be the code that I had added to my function.php

[image: the current mini-cart]

[image: code that I implemented]

[image: the result of my review order]

[image: The result of my cart review]

Comment: can you paste website URL so i can check!

Comment: Hey man, sorry the website is not up and is in a virtual machine. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: Ok give me moment , will check if i can check it quickly for you

Comment: Sorry buddy just to clarify more is the development happens in the intranet.

Answer (score 0):

Can add this and check

```
.mini-cart li {
 position:relative;
}
.mini-cart li ul{
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
}
.mini-cart li:hover ul{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: Hi Neal, thanks for the reply but unfortunately I had decided to remove the mini cart. Thanks, bud. But I had tried for the CSS you provided beforehand and it seems is not working as well. Anyway thanks man.

Comment: I can get better idea if there will be live url , rest i can just assume the view only